# Fetch data hyperlink name from SQL

Tags: php, html, sql

So I have a basic PHP SQL query that prints data from table (Search engine). I would like the results to be displayed as hyperlink (this I can do it).

Now, when the user would click on the link of one of the name fetched from sql, it would open a new html page and show all the détails of that name.

---

Example : If I have a table with 3 column : FirstName | Name | Address

I will print the column name based on a user search, and then when the user click on the name hyperlink it would show them the first name and address and maybe more data from other tables.

I have no idea how to do that, thanks

Comment: You could use html form with PHP POST. Then you can grab on the next page and query the data that needs to be display. Pretty basic PHP.

Comment: thanks. I found a way to do it by passing the variable in the URL and then getting it with $test = $_GET["id"];   is it a good way ?

Comment: That works. That is usually how it is down with MVC frameworks.